# Jsp no reconoce archivos Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, jsp, java-ee, servlets

estoy haciendo una aplicacion web con JavaEE y necesito pasar ciertos parámetros desde un Servlet a una Jsp, lo hago así:

```
request.setAttribute("car", per.getCarrera().getNombre());
```

Y para la redirección:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/odontologia/Tratamiento.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

El problema es que haciendolo de esta forma no se reconocen los enlaces a archivos Javascript que están en la página JSP, están declarados así:

```
<script src="../assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
```

También he probado con rutas Absolutas pero sigue sin enlazar los .js

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
```

Si la redirección la realizo con:

```
response.sendRedirect();
```

Me reconoce los archivos .js pero no puedo enviar los parámetros ¿Alguna forma de hacer esto sin usar la sesión? y otra pregunta ¿En que ocasiones es correcto usar la sesión para pasar las variables del Servlet a Jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP no tiene nada que ver con el JS. El navegador recibe HTML (que venga de JSP o no le trae sin cuidado) y al procesarlo y ver que incluye recursos (que pueden ser archivos JS o de imagen o cualquier otro) calcula las URLs de esos recursos y hace las peticiones correspondientes.

Los dos métodos que empleas significan cosas completamente distintas:

- `sendRedirect` devuelve al navegador un código HTTP Redirect (302) con la URL; el navegador **hace otra petición** a la dirección que se le indica.
- `forward` no devuelve nada al navegador. Lo que hace es pasar esa misma petición a otro componente *para que la continúe procesando*

Si envías una petición a http://miservidor.ejemplo/index:

- Un redirect a http://miservidor.ejemplo/eljsp hará que tu navegador haga una petición a esta URL y muestre el resultado. La URL del navegador será http://miservidor.ejemplo/eljsp
- Un forward a http://miservidor.ejemplo/eljsp hará que dentro de la misma petición a "index" el servidor invoque "eljsp.jsp" y devuelva el resultado dentro de la misma petición a "index". La URL del navegador se mantiene en http://miservidor.ejemplo/index.

Así que mira la URL del navegador. Eso te dirá qué recurso estás accediendo, y cuál es la URL relativa que tiene que aparecer en el HTML para acceder al JS.